# Share route parameters between actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following two routes

```cs
[Route("{tenant}/Index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("{tenant}/About")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

I'd like to link from one view to the other using this:

```html
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-tenant="bouke">Index</a>
<a asp-action="About" asp-route-tenant="bouke">Index</a>
```

This will render the expected output:

```html
<a href="/bouke/Index">Index</a>
<a href="/bouke/About">Index</a>
```

However I don't want to pass the `asp-route-tenant` on each link. Similarly to `asp-controller` which takes the current controller if not specified. However the following doesn't just work:

```html
<a asp-action="Index">Index</a>
<a asp-action="About">Index</a>
```

When rendered from the About page, this will render as:

```html
<a href="">Index</a>
<a href="/bouke/About">Index</a>
```

So two questions regarding this:

- How can I forgo having to define the tenant route parameter on all links?
- Is there a way to have Asp.Net throw an exception if it can't find a proper route, instead of failing silently and producing non-working links?

Comment: You can get `<a href="/bouke/About">Index</a>` correctly is because it is in `About` page.If you don't use `asp-route-tenant` and the action name is different from view name,it cannot get the parmeter `{tenant}`.

Comment: Both routes have a route-value called `tenant`. I don't want to have to pass that route-value around everywhere, let the framework look it up from the current route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add custom decorator that automatically applies tenant to the link

Here is a sample code from Finbuckle.MultiTenant:

[AmbientValueLinkGenerator.cs](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/blob/main/samples/ASP.NET%20Core%203/IdentityDataIsolationSample/Infrastructure/AmbientValueLinkGenerator.cs)

and update your startup class as this:

[Startup.cs](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/blob/main/samples/ASP.NET%20Core%203/IdentityDataIsolationSample/Startup.cs)

In case when I needed to handle case where a tenant was not in the link or invalid I created a custom IPageFilter that would redirect user to a default page in my case where tenant should be selected

```
    public class TenantRouteFilter : IPageFilter
    {
        private readonly string _pathToTenantSelection;

        public TenantRouteFilter(string pathToTenantSelection)
        {
            _pathToTenantSelection = pathToTenantSelection;
        }

        public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
        {

        }

        public void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
        {
//Check if user is authenticated and that we are not on page we are trying to redirect to
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
                !context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Contains(_pathToTenantSelection, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var name = context.HttpContext.GetTenant();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    context.Result = new RedirectResult($"/default{_pathToTenantSelection}");
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnPageHandlerExecuted(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

And in Startup.cs

```
  services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new TenantRouteFilter("/TenantSelection"));
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this out! What about the second bullet point? How can I have ASP.NET throw an exception if it cannot generate a route because of missing route values?

Comment: Would say inside the AmbientValueLinkGenerator.cs class. That's where you control how link is generated, if that makes sense?

Comment: After some more testing I discovered that this solution will add the selected ambient value to every generated link, even when the route doesn't need the parameter. So when a route doesn't need `{tenant}`, the generated url will have `tenant=bouke` added to the query parameters.